# How do I make a opaque shape always hide everything staying behind it?

Tags: css

```css
#circle { width: 100px; height: 100px;
          position: relative;
          background: gray; opacity: .6;
          margin: 0 auto; 
          border-radius: 50%; 
          z-index: 2;}
#line  { display: block; position: relative;
          width: 100%; height: 5px;
          background: red; top: -50px;
          z-index: 1;}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

How to make parts of the red line that stay behind the circle invisible? Without changing the opacity of the circle to 1.

Comment: I think this is an [**XY problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Paulie_D so what is the "Y" Problem?

Comment: You are asking how to make a translucent element behave like an opaque one without becoming opaque. That's a contradiction.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith The opacity isn't the issue as such...it's the fact that the initial problem is caused by having a single element forming the line...when it could be two.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate "line" div for this.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background:grey;  
}

#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.5); /* semi-transparent green */
  opacity: .6;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#circle:before,
#circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50vw;
  top:50%;
  height: 5px;

}

#circle:before {
  left:0;
  transform:translate(-100%,-50%);
  background:red;
}
#circle:after {
  left:100%;
  transform:translate(0,-50%);
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: So I know your answer is far more correct then mine. However, is there really a difference? before and after is basically one over another right? Hypothetically speaking.

Comment: After, reading your other comment below the question, this makes a lot more sense now, thank you!

Comment: Not really, my lines don't go behind the div at all.

Comment: But that's only approximate, right? E.g. if the line was thicker, it wouldn't follow the curve of the circle. Also only works assuming you want the line to go through the centre...

Comment: Yes, you are right but that seems to be the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Put a your circle inside a white circle see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v61bguns/

**HTML**

```
<div id="circle2"><div id="circle"></div></div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#circle2 { width: 100px; height: 100px;
          position: relative;
          background: white;
          margin: 0 auto; 
          border-radius: 50%; 
          z-index: 2;}
#circle { width: 100px; height: 100px;
          position: relative;
          background: gray; opacity: .6;
          margin: 0 auto; 
          border-radius: 50%; 
          z-index: 3;}
#line  { display: block; position: relative;
          width: 100%; height: 5px;
          background: red; top: -50px;
          z-index: 1;}
```

Comment: Thanks, see how easy it is really makes me feel dumb :(